# How to solve a $10$ degree Polynomial? (without using the normal tricks)

Tags: polynomials, algorithms, problem-solving, factoring

The problem specifically is a $x^{10}$ polynomial over $x^9$ polynomial that we have to graph.

To graph, we need to find all the vertical intercepts so both polynomial need to be factored.

Is there any algorithm or application downloadable to a calculator to solve this problem?

The obvious way is to use synthetic division to find. But there are over $100$ combinations of possible values for each polynomial, so I was just thinking there had to be some faster way.

Comment: Could you give us the exact problem you are meant to solve?

Comment: graph the polynomial and pick the factor?

Comment: If you are asking if there is a way to factor an arbitrary degree 10 polynomial, no.  It cannot be done for the general case (*google search for "unsolvability of the quintic"*).  If you are asking if you can factor *some* degree 10 polynomials, yes, but those are rarer.  Usually if you are intended to be able to factor by hand, the roots are easily seen by inspection.  Check integers close to zero first.

Comment: To plot the graph of any function, you have to find a few function values and plot them. Have you tried that first?

Comment: For the *vertical* intercepts, or y-intercept, you should be able to just plug 0 in for x and evaluate.  Assuming y is a function of x, there should be just one y-intercept.